# Serilog.Sinks.MongoDB not logging into local MongoDB

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-standard, serilog

1. Using Below code, unable to log into mongoDB

   ```
    var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
               .WriteTo.MongoDB("mongodb://Localhost/logs", collectionName: "applog")
               .MinimumLevel.Debug()
               .CreateLogger();
       log.Information("Log From app");
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code "period: TimeSpan.Zero"
    .WriteTo.MongoDB("mongodb://Localhost/logs", period: TimeSpan.Zero)

Answer (score 0):

you should use period time and your code will be something like that

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {  
             SelfLog.Out = Console.Error;
            Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));
            var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.MongoDB("mongodb://Localhost/logs", collectionName: "applog",period:TimeSpan.Zero)
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .CreateLogger();
            log.Error("Log From app");
            for (int i = 0; i <500 ; i++)
            {
                log.Error("Log From app" + i);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
```